# Why does Visual Studio 2010 C# debugger show different order than in class definition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

We're constructing a buffer of bytes to send out on a .Net Socket *Send()* method to some factory equipment so the byte order matters.     But I've noticed that even when I use "[StructLayout(**LayoutKind.Sequential**," the Visual Studio 2010 debugger shows a different sequence than I specify.   For example,

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  public class K_NEWFILEGET_START
  {
      public K_HEADER Header = new K_HEADER();
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
      public byte[] fileName = new byte[32];
      public globals.INT2_Type crc = new globals.INT2_Type();
  }
```

then I do a

```
 K_NEWFILEGET_START msg = new K_NEWFILEGET_START();
```

In the debugger it shows . . .

```
-    msg      {xxxxx.yyy.K_NEWFILEGET_START}        
+    crc      {xxxxx.globals.INT2_Type}     
+    fileName {byte[32]}                        
+    Header   {xxxxx.yyy.K_HEADER}
```

(proprietary stuff xxx'ed out)    In this example it's in the reverse order but I have other examples where the displayed order in the debugger is scrambled in different ways.

If I take it one step further and examine the actual output on the network, using a network sniffer,  it seems to be in the correct order I specified, so the debugger seems to be the problem but I'd like to see it correctly.    BTW I **do** have "show raw structure of objects in variables windows" set in the debugger options.
 Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger is showing you the members in alphabetical order.

That's usually more convenient when debugging large structures withe a lot of stuff in them.

Comment: You know, I noticed that it was in alphabetical order and I was going to look into whether that might be the reason, but I thought, "Naaah, they wouldn't do that!"

Answer (score 1):

Sure looks like it's in alphabetical order...

If the network sniffer is showing it correctly then most likely the debugger is simply trying to "help" you by putting the variable names in alphabetical order so you can locate them easier.